# MySQL SUM calculation

Tags: php, sum

Hi i'm having some trouble getting the results I need. I have the following table and I just want to be able to get the grand total for the Total column. Some explanation here.
For the "Total" column I'm using the code below. How can I get the Grand Total in this case?
[image]

```
<td class="text-center">
                    <?php
                    foreach ( $all_products as $product ) {
                        
                        if ( $stock['product_id'] == $product['id'] ) { $total = ($product['sale_price'] * $stock['quantity']); 
                        echo formatcurrency($total);}
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
```

Comment: For a MySQL answer, you should include the SQL you used. There is likely an approach using ROLLUP, but you didn't include the SQL so I can't give you a valid answer. If you don't want a SQL approach, remove the MySQL tag from your question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Paste the table data as text here instead. (If you want it pretty, you can use a formatting tool like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for that.)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant SQL tags

Answer (score 0):

You can add one variable to calculate the grand total. Try below code

```
    <td class="text-center">
        <?php
            $gtot   = 0;
            foreach ( $all_products as $product ) {
            
                    if ( $stock['product_id'] == $product['id'] ) { 
                        $total = ($product['sale_price'] * $stock['quantity']); 
                        echo formatcurrency($total);
                        $gtot = $gtot + $total;
                    }
            }
            echo 'Grand Total = '.$gtot;
        ?>
    </td>
```

Here I have used $gtot, use it anywhere you want, I have used your code assuming $total working as expected. If you want to fecth sum from the database directly then can use SUM() method of mysql.

```
SELECT SUM(`product`.`sale_price`*`stock`.`quantity`) 
FROM `product` INNER JOIN `stock` ON
`product`.`product_id`=`stock`.`product_id`
```

Use the above sql and please use correct column/table names as per your database.

Comment: You might also want to echo the grand total somewhere, since you went to the effort of calculating it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact they are from 2 different tables. product_id and quantity from stock table and sale_price from products table. And from your first answer I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)  error

Comment: @AlexSilva, edited my answer, please remove var.

Comment: removing "var" worked but it is giving me the same results as the "total" column. I need to add all values from the "Total" column.

Comment: I think you echoed $gtot inside the for loop, edited my answer, try printing $gtot outside the loop.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your help here but I'm still not getting what I need. below is what I"m getting. I just need the Grand total in this case $1060.00
Qty Total Grand Total
2 $30.00  $30.00 Grand Total = 30
3 $318.00  $318.00 Grand Total = 318
2 $190.00  $190.00 Grand Total = 190
1 $140.00  $140.00 Grand Total = 140
2 $138.00  $138.00 Grand Total = 138
1 $106.00  $106.00 Grand Total = 106
2 $138.00  $138.00 Grand Total = 138

Comment: I can see Grand total is echoed so many times, and earlier I suggested to print it outside the loop, check my edited answer

Comment: still not getting it :-( but thanks for your help

Comment: I think you have not provided the full source here, this line - if ( $stock['product_id'] == $product['id'] ) {, from where did you got the $stock array? And if the rest of the code working fine, then Grand total must be displayed properly, either edit your question with full source code or provide better explanation

Comment: Your help and patience is really appreciated here. OK from the table in the picture i was able to get the total value for each individual product. Simple math . Unit price * Quantity. Now I just want to get the Grand total for the entire table. Just one line with the SUM of all individual Total. The code I provided in the beginning is working fine. I just don't know how to add all "totals" together.